# JMETER POST Request how to ensure data is updated in database

Tags: database, post, jmeter

I am trying to test a Java webpage. And i have a JMETER post request with some parameters . The response code is 200 when i run the request. But the data is not updated in database.how do i ensure the post request is updated in the database and gets viewed in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Keep [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and make a query to retrieve the inserted data.

Then, keep an Assertion (As a child to JDBC Request) on the query result, to check whether the value is part of the query result. If not present, Sampler will be marked as Failed.

---

You can also assert the HTTP Sampler response if its response contains any successful code/message/value related to the value.